# import feed parser in my django app is throwing an error

Tags: python, django, heroku, feedparser

I installed my dependencies using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I then went to my views but the word feedparser is throwing an error in my pycharm ide. I did pip freeze and I can see that it's installed. So I tried installing it by itself and got the following message

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): feedparser in /Users/ray/Desktop/uply/sat/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

I then followed the path to see if it was really their and it is it says

```
feedparser-5.2.1.dist-info
```

I don't get what's going on because it works in another app that I have. I'm basically just copying it from my old app and putting it in my new app I'm getting ready to deploy onto heroku. What is my issue? all guidance is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using virtual environment?
If yes, then in pyCharm check the python path if its defined correct and picking the right path where the dependencies are installed.
It seems your ide is not able to pick the right path.

Comment: The path and evertything checks out. It's going to the same location as the other dependencies. The thing is if I go into python shell and do the following >>>import feedparser  >>>d = feedparser.parse('http://www.fameolous.com/feed/') >>>d it will output all the info, and If I do the same thing in my view it outputs it correctly but it just has a red underline like theres an error @kavitanjalisingh

Comment: Can you please provide the response you are getting? If output is correct then whats the problem now?